# How can I change a data value with CoreData in SwiftUI?

Tags: core-data, swiftui

## Change the value of a data using CoreData and SwiftUI

I'm trying to modify a boolean value `isFavorite` of a data with a button (heart) on a cell in a list.

**Modele data**

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

public class VoitureItem: NSManagedObject, Identifiable {


    @NSManaged public var marque: String?
    @NSManaged public var modele: String?
    @NSManaged public var annee: String?
    @NSManaged public var energie: String?
    @NSManaged public var kilometrage: String?
    @NSManaged public var isFavorite: Bool

}

extension VoitureItem {
    static func getAllVoitureItems() -> NSFetchRequest<VoitureItem> {

        let request:NSFetchRequest<VoitureItem> = VoitureItem.fetchRequest() as! NSFetchRequest<VoitureItem>

        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "isFavorite", ascending: false)

        request.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

         return request   
    }  
}
```

[image: ScreenShot of ContentView result]

I use in my `ContentView` a `managedObjectCOntext` and a `FetchRequest` to show all the data in a `List` and to create new data. 
**I would like to know how I can just click on the button change the value of `isFavorite` in my CoreData.**

**ContentView() (main view)**

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
    @FetchRequest(fetchRequest: VoitureItem.getAllVoitureItems()) var voitureItems: FetchedResults<VoitureItem>


    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {//show list of all the data}
        }
     }
```

**Button on the cell**

```
Button(action: {

                //var fav: Bool = false
                print("favorite")

                //HERE - Change isFavorite in coreData

            }) {
                if isFavorite {
                    Image(systemName: "heart.fill")
                        .foregroundColor(Color.yellow)
                } else {
                    Image(systemName: "heart")
                        .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work.

```
List(voitureItems) { item in
    ItemCell(item: $item)
}
```

...

```
struct ItemCell: View {

    @Binding var item: VoitureItem

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            item.isFavourite.toggle()
        }) {
            if item.isFavourite {
                Image(systemName: "heart.fill")
                    .foregroundColor(Color.yellow)
            } else {
                Image(systemName: "heart")
                    .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I try to use your answer, but `item: $item` gives me an error : `Use of unresolved identifier '$item'`

Comment: Try without the $